# Problema com imagens no plugin Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: plugin, wordpress

Estou utilizando o Advanced Custom Fields em um trabalho e criei o seguinte campo

[image]

e inseri fora do loop o código:

```
<?php the_field('jogador_1'); ?>
```

e está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
 15, , foto10, , , image/jpeg, http://localhost/projects/tribuna/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/foto10.jpg, 910, 1283, Array.
```

Answer (score 2):

O que está retornando não é um erro. Você configurou o Field para retornar um "Objeto da imagem". Então está imprimindo um objeto completo. Atenção que às vezes fora do loop pode não funcionar se não colocarmos o ID: `the_field($meu_field, $post_id)`.

Uma opção é trocar a configuração para "URL da imagem" e manter seu código.

Mantendo a configuração atual, faça:

```
$imagem = get_field('jogador_1');
var_dump($imagem);
echo '<img src="' . $imagem['KEY-DO-VAR-DUMP'] . '" />';
```

Ou confira a [documentação para o field de imagem](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/).

---

<sub>O `var_dump()` é uma técnica básica de *debugging*. Uso muito também o seguinte:</sub>

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $VARIAVEL_QUE_QUERO_INSPECIONAR, true ) . '</pre>';
```